# Is checking for null redundant while using Contract Annotator from JetBrains?

Tags: java, null

I'm curious whether checking for `null` is redundant in this concrete example.

```
 public LoginJob(@NotNull String login, @NotNull String password) {
        super(new Params(Priority.NORMAL).requireNetwork().persist());
        Preconditions.checkNotNull(login, "login is null or empty");
        Preconditions.checkNotNull(password, "password is null or empty");

        this.login = login;
        this.password = password;
    }
```

Please notice I'm using [Contract Annotator](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/documentation/howto.html) from JetBrains, so the User of a Class warned the `LoginJob` constructor can't take `null` values, it can't prevent him/her of doing so though.

Comment: The only time null checks are unnecessary is if you ban null from your entire code base. Then you only need to check for null where your code interacts with third party code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You said it yourself in your question :

> it can't prevent him/her of doing so though.

That settle it for me. You still have the responsibility to prevent that `null` value are pass to your classes. The annotation seems to be about preventing `NullPointerException`. So you should be checking for `null` values even if you use `@NotNull`.

> ```
>     Preconditions.checkNotNull(login, "login is null or empty");
>     Preconditions.checkNotNull(password, "password is null or empty");
> ```

Your message or the method you use is lying. The method is called `checkNotNull` but you warn about empty `String`, this is two very different things. Either you should modify you message to inform that you're only checking `null` values or you could change/rename the method `checkNotNull` to better represent the empty check.

Comment: Isn't that the user's fault if he/she is ignorant about using the method? You tell him not to provide `null` values (, or unexpected behavior might occur). If he does, he's in trouble, and it's his own fault. However, a clear note that the project uses this approach might be necessary.

Comment: @NiekHaarman You could do that kind of approach, I think it's indeed a valid way of doing things (You could add this point as an answer). I would prefer to use something that fails early and gracefully over one that could break somewhere I didn't expect. `Preconditions.checkNotNull` throw a `NullPointerException` so it will behave "as if" he would not had made the check. I"m not sure but I believe that the `@NotNull` annotation the OP use is "valid" only in Intellij, so user with Eclipse could potentially not see those warnings (I'm very not sure about this point).

Comment: You have a very good point there: `I would prefer to use something that fails early and gracefully`. I'm not very happy about cluttering the code with these precondition checks though (Although, I must say, using `Preconditions.checkNotNull` solves a bit of the cluttering over `if` statements).